# Does MySQL eliminate common subexpressions between SELECT and HAVING/GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization, having

I often see people answer MySQL questions with queries like this:

```
SELECT DAY(date), other columns
FROM table
GROUP BY DAY(date);

SELECT somecolumn, COUNT(*)
FROM table
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I always like to give the column an alias and refer to that in the `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT DAY(date) AS day, other columns
FROM table
GROUP BY day;

SELECT somecolumn, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM table
HAVING c > 1;
```

Is MySQL smart enough to notice that the expressions in the later clauses are the same as in `SELECT`, and only do it once? I'm not sure how to test this -- `EXPLAIN` doesn't show any difference, but it doesn't seem to show how it's doing the grouping or filtering in the first place; it seems mainly useful for optimizing joins and `WHERE` clauses.

I tend to be pessimistic about MySQL optimization, so I like to give it all the help I can.

Comment: Just in case you need an immediate answer, as a stop-gap until I can find an authoritative reference (and I suspect that it might have to be from the source), I'm pretty sure that the parser recognises calls to deterministic functions (and indeed, expressions) and caches the result for reuse in a query.

Comment: +1 A coherent and useful question!

Comment: @eggyal I don't need anything immediately, it's more curiosity. I wonder whether I should recommend people improve their answers when I see this redundancy. I plan on continuing to write my queries the second way because I find them more readable.

Comment: Barmar asking a question? I fear my compass has been irreversibly decalibrated.

Comment: This is actually [a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16152533) (and no doubt others - I'm pretty sure I've addressed this question before, albeit perhaps as a sub-part of another question), but I'm not convinced by the answers in that linked question and think this offers a better opportunity to produce a canonical reference.

Comment: One simple demonstration of the fact that function results are cached is [`SELECT RAND() FROM table ORDER BY RAND()`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba206/1/0) - since the resulting column is indeed sorted, MySQL must have used the same value for both calls to `RAND()`.

Comment: Good one! I wonder if we can come up with a similar test for `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Not sure how best to demonstrate that, but given `GROUP BY` is implemented by performing a sort...

Comment: Am trying to put together a slightly more authoritative answer based on the optimizer source code - just thought that was worth mentioning for now.

Comment: I highly doubt rand() is cached. What if you have two rand() functions? I just tried select rand(),rand() and the both cols contain different values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this can be tested using sleep() function,
for example take a look at this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bc1b/1

```
Select * FROM t;

| X |
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

SELECT x+sleep(1)
FROM t
GROUP BY x+sleep(1);

SELECT x+sleep(1) As name
FROM t
GROUP BY name;
```

Execution times of both queries are about 3000 ms ( 3 seconds ).
There are 3 records in the table, and for each record the query sleeps for 1 second only,
so it means that the expression is evaluated only once for each record, not twice.

Comment: Further 'proof' is when you change _one_ of the sleeps to (2).  Now it takes 9 seconds.

Comment: `select x+sleep(1), count(*) from t group by x+sleep(1)` takes 6 seconds. What happens? Maybe the original example is just transformed to `select distinct x+sleep(1) from t`.

Comment: Additionally: `select x+sleep(1) as c from t having c > 0` also takes 6 seconds. So i guess, every alias is internally replaced by the expression behind it and evaluated every time again.

Comment: But...  `SLEEP()` is not really "deterministic".  `SQRT` is; `RAND` is not -- hence it would be 'ok' for `SQRT` to be remembered, but `RAND` may not.  OTOH, `NOW()` is deliberately remembered, but `SYSDATE` is not.

Answer (score 1):

After consulting with one of the MySQL engineers, I proffer this lengthy answer.

- Caching - no part of a query is 'remembered' for later use in that (or subsequent) query.  (Contrast: the Query cache.)
- Common subexpression elimination - no.  This is a common Compiler technique, but MySQL does not use it.  Example:  `(a-b)*(a-b)` will do the subtract twice.
- Removal of a constant from a loop - yes, with limitations.  This is another Compiler technique.
- A variety of SQL-centric hacks - yes; see below.
- Re-evaluation of a subquery - it depends.  Also, the Optimizer is gradually getting better.
- `VIEWs` - it depends.  There are still cases where a `VIEW` is destined to perform worse than the equivalent `SELECT`.  Example: no condition pushdown into a `UNION` in a `VIEW`.  Actually, this is more a matter of delayed action.
- I think that some newer versions of MariaDB have a "subquery cache".

(Caveat:  I do not have 100% confidence in any of my answer, but I do believe that most of it is correct, as of MySQL 5.7, MariaDB 10.1, etc)

Think of a multi-row `SELECT` as a loop.  Many, maybe all, "deterministic" expressions are evaluated once.  Example: Constant date expressions, even involving function calls.  But...

`NOW()` is specifically evaluated once at the beginning of a query.  Furthermore, the value is passed to Slaves when replicating.  That is, by the time the query is stored on a slave, `NOW()` could be out of date.  (`SYSDATE()` is another animal.)

Especially with the advent of `only_full_group_by`, `GROUP BY` needs to know if it matches the `SELECT` expressions.  So, this looks for similar code.

`HAVING` and `ORDER BY` can use aliases from the `SELECT` list (unlike `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`).  So  `SELECT expr AS x ... HAVING expr` seems to reevaluate `expr`, but `SELECT expr AS x ... HAVING x` seems to reach for the already-evaluated `expr`.

The Windowing functions of MariaDB 10.2 have some pretty severe restrictions on where they can/cannot be reused; I don't have a complete picture of them yet.

Generally, none of this matters -- the re-evaluation of an expression (`DATE(date)` or even `COUNT(*)`) will get the same answer.  Furthermore, the rummaging through the rows is usually much more costly than expression evaluation.  So, unless you have a good stopwatch, you won't tell the difference.

Comment: Considering the demonstration in the other answer, does this mean that it considers `SLEEP(1)` to be a deterministic expression, so it evaluates it only once?

Comment: Deterministic - no.  Else the query would have taken 1 sec, not 3.  I think `x+sleep(1)` comes under the weasel words I spoke on `GROUP BY`.  Note that `GROUP BY x+sleep(2)` takes 9 seconds; I don't know if `x` gets involved in the `only_full_group_by` checking.